# How to slerp quaternion from zero radians to 2PI radians

Tags: graphics

I am using quaternion to solve the angle animation interpolation

```
- (GLKMatrix4)interpolate:(float)progress
{
   GLKMatrix4 R1 = GLKMatrix4MakeZRotation(0);
   GLKMatrix4 R2 = GLKMatrix4MakeZRotation(M_PI * 2);
   GLKQuaternion quat = GLKQuaternionSlerp(GLKQuaternionMakeWithMatrix4(R1), 
   GLKQuaternionMakeWithMatrix4(R2), progress);
   return GLKMatrix4MakeWithQuaternion(quat);
}
```

however , i find 2*PI is equal to 0 radians in rotation , so the interpolation between zero radians and 2PI radians is zero radians all the time ?
how could i solve the problem ? please

Answer (score 0):

Since both GLKMatrix4MakeZRotation(0) and GLKMatrix4MakeZRotation(M_PI * 2) yield the same `unit matrix`, interpolation between them will have no effect. If you'd like to achieve 2PI rotation, interpolate quaternions in 0 to PI/2 range. Then quadruple it afterwards.

```
- (GLKMatrix4)interpolate:(float)progress
{
   GLKMatrix4 R1 = GLKMatrix4MakeZRotation(0);
   GLKMatrix4 R2 = GLKMatrix4MakeZRotation(M_PI / 2);
   GLKQuaternion quat = GLKQuaternionSlerp(GLKQuaternionMakeWithMatrix4(R1), 
       GLKQuaternionMakeWithMatrix4(R2), progress);
   quat = GLKQuaternionMultiply(quat, quat);
   quat = GLKQuaternionMultiply(quat, quat);
   return GLKMatrix4MakeWithQuaternion(quat);
}
```

Comment: yes , it's a concise answer ;   i tried another solution : convert my matrix to euler angles then interpolate between angles